# How is it possible for beeline to list hdfs without a valid kerberos tgt?

Tags: hive, hdfs, kerberos, beeline

```
0: jdbc:hive2://asok-1-openstack.com:2181,aso> !sh hdfs dfs -ls /
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.5.0-152/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/3.1.5.0-152/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Found 9 items
drwxrwxrwt   - yarn   hadoop          0 2021-01-30 08:10 /app-logs
drwxr-xr-x   - yarn   hadoop          0 2021-01-30 08:07 /ats
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2021-01-30 08:07 /atsv2
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2021-01-30 08:07 /hdp
drwxr-xr-x   - mapred hdfs            0 2021-01-30 08:07 /mapred
drwxrwxrwx   - mapred hadoop          0 2021-01-30 08:07 /mr-history
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2021-02-03 12:21 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2021-01-30 14:54 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs   hdfs            0 2021-01-30 14:54 /warehouse
0: jdbc:hive2://asok-1-openstack.com:2181,aso> !sh pwd
/tmp/hsperfdata_hive
0: jdbc:hive2://asok-1-openstack.com:2181,aso> !sh id
uid=1008(hive) gid=1002(hadoop) groups=1002(hadoop) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
0: jdbc:hive2://asok-1-openstack.com:2181,aso> !sh klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1008
Default principal: hive/asok-2-openstack.com@OPENSTACK.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
05/04/2021 12:28:09  05/05/2021 12:28:09  krbtgt/OPENSTACK.COM@OPENSTACK.COM
0: jdbc:hive2://asok-1-openstack.com:2181,also>
```

Here one can see that my user `hive` has a valid ticket for only the hive service.
While `hdfs dfs -ls /` will need a valid ticket to connect to the namenode service; how is the user `hive` able to connect to the namenode service without a valid ticket?

Comment: Depends on the **security model** used by your Hive services. Authorization managed by Sentry? by Ranger? implicitly via HDFS privs of the current user _(do not use `hive` service account to run queries, ue actual user creds)_? by some other mechanism?

Comment: `hive` is typically a privileged **proxy user** account, it is able to impersonate (almost) any user. Like `oozie`, `hue`, `livy`, `knox` etc. Check `core-site.xml` used by HDFS and YARN services for details.